# ServiceM8 - can I filter on more than one field

Tags: rest

I am looking into an integration with ServiceM8 and would like to use the $filter REST API to filter by more than one. Something like company_uuid and status. The ServiceM8 documentation give they following example but does not include any use for 'OR'/'AND' type logic.

```
"https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/job.json?%24filter=company_uuid%20eq%20'10420f98-7626-4405-bf43-043f1036623b'
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

You can still filter by most of the fields, but only **one**.

**Exclude Completed Jobs**:

- The filter (in a whole URL for context) to **exclude** completed jobs is:
- ```
  "https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/job.json?%24filter=status%20ne%20%22Completed%22"
  ```

- Construction:

  ```
  %24 : $
  %20 : (space)
  %22 : "
  &   : &
  "   : "
  ```

---

It still cannot be used in conjunction with any other filter as far as I can see.  Adding filters either causes a 500 error, or one filter will work and the other will be ignored, or it even sometimes gives a return response telling you not to bother:

- ```
  {"errorCode":400,"message":"Advanced Record Filter Queries Not Supported"}
  ```

The reality is that at the time of writing this, that isn't possible.  The functions on the [Filtering](http://developer.servicem8.com/docs/rest-api/filtering/) page (Currently last revision July 1, 2014) are the absolute extent of it's functionality.  Even then, it doesn't entirely work (For example, filtering for **active** status doesn't work at all).

Retrieving the whole end point is just as quick, but obviously depending on your application may have undesirable processing or bandwidth implications

Perhaps the halfway point would be selecting the most discriminative filter to retrieve your working data.

- I.e.  You can get all the jobs since 1st July 2016 using this filter:
- ```
  %24filter=date%20gt%20%222016-07-01%22
  ```

That specific example actually includes jobs on the 1st July (There's no **`ge`** filter available), but it's guess work, as you don't really know how it's applying **`gt`** to your data as the documentation only gives an example of matching an exact `uuid` and a single numeric comparison.

Comment: hmedia1, thanks for the response and advise. We will take that into consideration. We might be OK with all Jobs for a company but thinking ahead it would be nice to excluded "Completed" Jobs. We can certainly pull the entire end point and then filter on the client.

Comment: All good, you can at least exclude the completed ones using updated answer.

Comment: hmedia1, wow thx for the updated answer well done. But you know I had to test whether active status worked... yep doesn't work at all.

Comment: @kheiberg, I believe they have fixed the `active` filter now !

Comment: That would be excellent. I need to go check that out. How did you find out? Did they change their documentation? I am actually on my way to the documentation to find out...

Comment: @kheiberg not in the documentation, and something I just noticed.  Given that this always should have worked, I'd say they just treated it as a bug and fixed it.  It definitely works now, and it definitely didn't work when we tested it last year.