# How to apply the filter in the Jobpayment.json service of the ServiceM8 API

Tags: json, webhooks

I need to apply the multiple filter in the
Jobpayment.json
https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/JobPayment.json
service how can I apply

Also I need to remove the allow maximum time to access the service limit per minute in the ServiceM8 API.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

> I need to apply the multiple filter in the Jobpayment.json
>   https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/JobPayment.json service how can I
>   apply

TLDR; You can't use multiple filters through the API.  If you want to filter by multiple criteria, you need to retrieve the whole endpoint and filter it locally.

Refer to this answer for more information:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40400817/3544399

> Also I need to remove the allow maximum time to access the service
>   limit per minute in the ServiceM8 Api.

- You can e-mail ServiceM8 support, who can adjust the daily limit (quota) in certain circumstances.  Regardless, they will inform you that their system automatically adjusts the limits for each user as it sees valid usage of the API. The exact thresholds of these increase triggers are not publicly documented, but supposedly the system would aim to achieve a certain amount of headroom and automatically make adjustments as usage is consistent and increase is gradual.
- At the time of writing this, the per-minute limit is 60 (1 request per second).  This is fixed, and not subject to increase.  Attempting to exceed this limit will result in requests being throttled.